# Excel VBA script to create new sheet and edit formulas accordingly

Tags: vba, excel

This may seem trivial but I'm unable to get any hints for what I need to do for several weeks.

I have script that creates template for me. It's daily report so it does create the same table for each day of the month. However I also need this to update formulas in this template.

I have 2 documents. Lets call them `SOURCE` and `RESULTS`. `SOURCE` has 28 worksheets for each day of February. There is some data in `A1`. I have a script that creates `RESULTS` also for each day of the month based on template.

However each sheet (each day) refers to the same place in `SOURCE` because it just copies the table with formulas. So I end up with RESULTS with 28 worksheets where in each ***day formula refers to SOURCE's 1.Feb sheet***.

I need each worksheet to refer to respective day. So RESULTS's worksheet for 1.Feb refers to SOURCE's 1.Feb. RESULTS's 2.Feb refers to SOURCE's 2.Feb .. and so on.

Could anyone help?

here's the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim odpoved As Integer
    odpoved = MsgBox("Tento program ti pripravi prazdnu predlohu na XXX." & Chr(13) & "Pre pokracovanie stlac OK, pre ukoncenie programu alebo editaciu" & Chr(13) & "predlohy stlac Cancel!", vbOKCancel, "Welcome!")
    Select Case odpoved
        Case vbOK
            If odpoved = vbOK Then
                Call test
            End If
        Case vbCancel
            If odpoved = vbCancel Then
                MsgBox ("Proces ukonceny uzivatelom")
                GoTo Line2
            End If
    End Select
Line2:
End Sub


Sub test()
    '
    ' Open and work Macro
    '
    Dim selected_month As Long
    Dim day_count As Integer
    Dim day_loop As Integer
    Dim najdi_cestu As String
    najdi_cestu = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Input Box to get the month number user wants to work with
Line1:
    selected_month = 13
    While (selected_month < 1) Or (selected_month > 12)
        selected_month = Val(InputBox("Zadaj poradove cislo mesiaca"))

        If selected_month = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Wend
    'Script above will loop until 0 or 1 - 12 are inserted
    '
    'Select Case tells how many days there are in the selected month
    Select Case selected_month
        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
            day_count = 30
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
            day_count = 31
        Case Else
            day_count = 28
    End Select
    '
    For day_loop = day_count To 1 Step -1
        Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
        ActiveSheet.Name = day_loop & "." & Left(MonthName(selected_month), 3)
    Next day_loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Template").Delete
    ' Auto pathfinder
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=najdi_cestu & "Zmenový priebeh výroby " & Format(MonthName(selected_month)) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    MsgBox ("Tvoja predloha na mesiac " & Format(MonthName(selected_month)) & " bola ulozena do: " & najdi_cestu)
    ' manualny save
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\pz595v\Desktop\Finalna verzia\" & Format(MonthName(selected_month)) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    '    xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Line3:
End Sub
```

Comment: ***Please post your code.***

Comment: Much better. What is the formula that needs changing as well? The issue can be resolved in the `For day_loop` part. After `ActiveSheet.Name`, something like `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Formula = blahdiblah` where `blahdiblah` is a dynamically generated formula-string can fix this. :)

Comment: @BK201, what is the returned data type of `blahdiblah`? ;)

Comment: This is the formula that needs to change
='C:\Users\Desktop\[final.xls]1.febr'!$U$33 .
Or actuallly there are 8 of these.. the same, just refering to different cells

Comment: Are there any hints for this one ? I wasn't there for quite a few days and now I see this is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title of your post "Excel VBA script to create new sheet and edit formulas accordingly" this is how you can create a new sheet and edit its formulas:

```
'creates a new sheet
    Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
    set wrkSheet = Worksheets.Add("Worksheet Name")
'changes forumula
wrkSheet.cells(1, 1) = "=B1+C1"
```

Comment: You have to **Set** `wrkSheet = Worksheets.Add("Worksheet Name")` because `WorkSheet` type refers to an `Object`type and you have to **Set** an object.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to go home and try it on my personal laptop.. will let you knwo the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just like this; a `Select Case` is like an `If` so when you write:

```
Select Case odpoved
    Case vbOK
        If odpoved = vbOK Then
            Call test
        End If
    Case vbCancel
        If odpoved = vbCancel Then
            MsgBox ("Proces ukonceny uzivatelom")
            GoTo Line2
        End If
End Select
```

You should just write it like this:

```
Select Case odpoved
    Case vbOK 'this line checks if odpoved = vbOK
        Call test
    Case vbCancel 'this line checks if odpoved = vbCancel
        MsgBox ("Proces ukonceny uzivatelom")
        GoTo Line2
End Select
```

Since the condition `odpoved` is already checked by the `Select Case`.